What exactly is an unfair-labor-practices charge and what result is it intended to produce?
Recent news claims that negotiations with a striking union has broken down and the employer filed a complaint against the union. From NPR,

About 33,000 union machinists have been on strike since Sept. 14. Two days of talks this week failed to produce a deal, and Boeing filed an unfair-labor-practices charge against the International Association of Machinists and Aerospace Workers.

But the report also notes that at the same time, the company announced layoffs (related to cash flow problems relating to the strike) so if the intent was to fire the striking workers, it likely would have done so directly. President Reagan famously fired thousands of striking air traffic controllers so clearly there isn't a special protection for striking workers so what's going on?

This isn't a political question but it is a legal question and would be better on law.se

Regarding the opening sentence that ends with "and the employer filed a union." Filed a union?? That should be "and the employer filed a complaint against the union." I edited the question to that effect.

Yes, this is a question about laws protecting unions, not about politics. I am going to migrate this question to law stack exchange.

It's filed under the National Labor Relations Act of 1935. The Act mostly protects workers' rights to form a union and for a union to negotiate on their behalf ("collective bargaining"). But it stipulates that some "unfair labor practices" by both employer 29 U.S. Code § 158 (a) and labor union (b) are prohibited. AFAICT both are required (d) to bargain in "good faith", which in this case Boeing alleges the union(s) didn't do so by "issuing misinformation to its members about the status of negotiations". Alas the press coverage [I found] doesn't say what remedies Boeing is seeking--you'd have to look up the legal documents for that. These complaints fall under civil code, not criminal, by the way.
The labor dispute itself ostensibly appears to be that the union/machinists don't agree to the [company-]proposed wage increases. David Hammen's answer makes an interesting point that side-effect might be delaying some layoffs, but even longer press articles about the dispute (that I found) don't seem to mention this specific connection. AFAICT, the strike had started a couple of weeks before the layoffs were announced to the press, at least. Whether the union had more advanced notice or "sensed" them otherwise beforehand is hard to say based from where I'm sitting.
Perusing the NRLB FAQ though:

Strikers who engage in serious misconduct in the course of a strike may be refused reinstatement to their former jobs. This applies to both economic strikers and unfair labor practice strikers.
Examples of serious misconduct that could cause the employees involved to lose their right to reinstatement are:

Strikers physically blocking persons from entering or leaving a struck plant.
Strikers threatening violence against nonstriking employees.
Strikers attacking management representatives.


I'm guessing that if the union leaders are found guilty of misrepresenting something (related to the negotiations) to the members, this might count as "serious misconduct in the course of a strike" (since the examples are not exhaustive), so Boeing might be able to fire at least the union leadership for cause, if they win.

I've not been able to locate the docs for this case, but I did find one from 2013 https://www.nlrb.gov/case/19-CB-119657 AFAICT, that one was dismissed. Note that the complaints themselves are not on-line. They require a FOIA, as the page notes.

There is special protection for striking workers so long as the workers are not federal civil servants and so long as they don't have a contract that forbids going on strike. (There are other exceptions as well.) The air traffic controllers fired by Reagan went on strike illegally and hence could legally be fired by Reagan, and were indeed fired.
Regarding Boeing and the striking machinists, those machinists are employees of a private company under a union contract, and the contract does not contain a no-strike clause. The one thing that Boeing could not do was to fire those striking machinists -- so long as the strike remained a protected strike per the National Labor Relations Act. Boeing is claiming that the strike is no longer a protected strike due to the union acting in bad faith. If Boeing is successful in that claim (which will take time to wend its way through multiple layers of the National Labor Relations Board, and then possibly US courts), Boeing will then be able fire those striking machinists. Laying off other workers not in the striking union -- that's completely kosher.

(which will take time to wend its way through the courts) The National Labor Relations Board (NLRB) handles unfair labor practices complaints. See, Boeing tells NLRB Machinists leaders broke labor law, as strike continues for more detail.

@RickSmith I updated my answer based on your comment. However, the US courts (non-NLRB) can be involved if a party wishes to appeal an NLRB decision beyond the NLRB; the NLRB decision is not necessarily the end.

So as long as the dispute is not settled, the striking employees are effectively protected from getting fired for any other reason?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Boeing is bleeding money without those striking machinists working for them. Boeing cannot yet fire those striking employees until the dispute is resolved, which is exactly why Boeing is laying off / furloughing employees who are not involved in the strike.

@DavidHammen Boeing made lots and lots of profits until 2019. Surely they built up reserves for exactly such times. And the workers also have a right to strike. Unions are protected for a reason. Maybe Boeing management is simply pursuing the wrong strategy and that's why workers lose their job now. On the other hand, layoffs might be inevitable at some point. That was exactly the point of my comment, asking how long the strikers are protected from being fired.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Companies and shareholders generally look at the current profit/loss. If they have idle workers (because other workers are on strike) they aren't going to dig into their reserves to keep paying them, they'll furlough them until the strike is over.

@Barmer But then the other worker groups could also get on strike to be protected from firing/furloughing, or couldn't they?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Workers aren't paid by the company for being on strike, so the other workers on strike would be effectively furloughing themselves. Not only that, unemployment benefits do not generally apply to a strike, so it would be even worse. A union may have a strike fund and pay members themselves.

@user71659 So that's the downside to strikes: no pay from company nor unemployment insurance. Then it's only fair to strike I'd say. And the protection from being fired is only during the strike but you cannot strike forever. So it doesn't add up to much.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Union contracts generally contain provisions that make it very difficult to be fired, e.g. allowing a grievance process where union reps defend your job. They also require a seniority-based hiring/furlough system so individual workers cannot be picked out.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution While union contracts do contain protections for union members (it is indeed very hard to fire an individual union members), they also contain protections for the employer. In particular, organizing a strike is a nontrivial process. Individual workers who go on strike are essentially quitting their jobs--and can be terminated even if they are union members. A union-sanctioned strike takes time to organize and then get passed by the union voting process, a lot more time than it takes for the employer to furlough employees.
